# how to get payer_id programmatically in my java code?

Tags: java, paypal

In my code, I am trying to send to Paypal REST API the needed information and Paypal is giving me an "APPROVED" status but in order to finalize the payment, I need to execute the payment.

`payment.execute(accesstoken,paymentExecution)`... but I couldn't get the `payer_id` from the response.
Here is my code for further information and thanks for your help in advance!

```
public class PaypalPaymentWithCreditCardServlet {    

   // private static final long serialVersionUID = 734220724945040319L;

   // @Override
    public void init () throws Exception {

        InputStream is = PaypalPaymentWithCreditCardServlet.class.getResourceAsStream("/sdk_config.properties");
        try {
                PayPalResource.initConfig(is);
        } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
               // goto failure page. can't do anything without configuration file
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public boolean doPost (PaymentPojo paymentpojo) throws Exception {

        try {

            String accessToken = GenerateAccessToken.getAccessToken();            
            APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);

            final Payment payment = new PaymentBuilder().setBillingAddress(paymentpojo.getBillingAddress())
                                                        .setCreditCard(paymentpojo.getCreditCard())
                                                        .setPaymentDetail(paymentpojo.getDetails())
                                                        .setTransactionAmount(paymentpojo.getAmount())
                                                        .build();

            Payment createdPayment = payment.create(apiContext);            

            System.out.println(Payment.getLastResponse());

            System.out.println(String.format("created payment with id [%s] and status=[%s]", createdPayment.getId(), createdPayment.getState()));

            if(!createdPayment.getState().toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(PaypalState.APPROVED.getStatus())) {

                // payment is not created. throw an exception
                System.out.println("Payment handshake did not go through!!!");

                return false;

            }


            // if it is not created throw exception

          //  payment.execute(accessToken, paymentExecution);



          return true;  

        } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {

        }
        return false;


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For credit card payments, payer_id is the unique attribute (e.g email address) that you use to identify the user in your system and you would provide that for payment each time in payerID.

If you are not aware of the user's information, such as a guest checkout, you should not need to provide a payerID.

For paypal payments, payer_id always needs to be provided and is appended to redirect_url once the user approves the payment. Full docs are at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/

Comment: Thank you v.much @Avi Das ..I've managed to solve the problem thanks to your advice.  Now I got some problem...I have already made a successful REFUND with a Sale object but How do i find the REFUND ID? i got the id in a Json format by calling Sale.getLastResponse() but how do i programatically find this refund transation id?

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if your immediate question was answered? It would be best to open a new issue for your newer question and link it here so that other developers can find it easier. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry for kicking question after question. And i accept the solution provided above. And i'll follow the rules so that other developers could benefit from it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hey not a problem, feel free to comment the link to your newer question here though.